# How to filter a pandas dataframe by a date range without specifying the year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index as follows:

```
1970-01-01
1970-01-02
1970-01-03
...
2021-04-26
2021-04-27
...
```

How to filter it by a date range i.e. "02-01" : "04-05" with the following result:

```
1970-02-01
1970-02-02
...
1970-04-05
1971-02-01
1971-02-02
...
1971-04-05
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean indexing, for example:

```
m = ((df.index.month >= 2) & (df.index.month <= 4)) & (
    (df.index.day >= 1) & (df.index.day <= 5)
)

print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
            col1
Date            
1970-02-03     3
1970-02-04     4
1970-03-03     3
1970-04-04     5
```

---

EDIT: You can skip `>=1` for days:

```
m = ((df.index.month >= 2) & (df.index.month <= 4)) & (df.index.day <= 5)
print(df[m])
```

---

EDIT 2: Example:

Suppose you have this df:

```
         Date  value
0  1970-02-03      1
1  1970-02-04      2
2  1970-02-05      3
3  1970-02-06      4
4  1970-02-07      5
5  1971-02-03      6
6  1971-02-04      7
7  1971-02-05      8
8  1971-02-06      9
9  1971-02-07     10
```

Then convert the "Date" column to datetime, set index and filter it:

```py
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], dayfirst=False)
df = df.set_index("Date")

m = ((df.index.month >= 2) & (df.index.month <= 4)) & (
    (df.index.day >= 1) & (df.index.day <= 5)
)
print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
            value
Date             
1970-02-03      1
1970-02-04      2
1970-02-05      3
1971-02-03      6
1971-02-04      7
1971-02-05      8
```

---

EDIT 3:

For this df:

```
            value
Date             
1970-02-03      1
1970-02-27      2
1970-04-05      3
1970-05-06     44
1970-05-07     55
1970-02-03      1
1970-02-27      2
1970-04-05      3
1970-05-06     44
1970-05-07     55
```

This code:

```
year_min = df.index.min().year
year_max = df.index.max().year

m = [False] * len(df)
for y in range(year_min, year_max + 1):
    m = ((df.index >= f"{y}-02-01") & (df.index <= f"{y}-04-05")) | m

print(df[m])
```

Prints:

```
            value
Date             
1970-02-03      1
1970-02-27      2
1970-04-05      3
1970-02-03      1
1970-02-27      2
1970-04-05      3
```

Comment: greater than equal to 1 is redundant in terms of dates

Comment: greater than or equal is also unnecessary additional computation when greater than or less than will suffice

Comment: That was my first approach. But "df.index.day <= 5" would exclude i.e. 02-06, which should be part of the range. I want to filter ALL days between 02-03 : 04-04 over all years.

Comment: @Andrej: It's just a continous dataframe over 15-20 years. I want to filter arbitrary time ranges like xxxx-03-17 - xxxx-05-29 and get all days between this timespan of all years.

Comment: @user2001245 I've edited my answer and put there an example. Make sure you have properly converted the datetimes (months/days) and the index is set.

Comment: Maybe my notation "02-01" : "04-05" was confusing. I meant the interval "february 1st UNTIL april 5th". Also i.e. the 1971-02-07 or 2021-03-27 should be part of that interval.

Comment: Ok,  thanks. I thought there could be a pandas shortcut I've overseen, but that should work.